# karma testing for $scope item not working / item not fired by $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I created a directive for my AngularJS app which checks the $scope to see if a profile image is present. If it is the directive shows the image by appending a new DIV, if not it shows a default via a css class. The directive looks like so... and it works in the app.

```
    .directive('profileImage',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                profileImage: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                if(!scope.profileImage) {
                    element.addClass('icon-default-profile-image defaultProfileImage');
                } else {
                    element.append('<img ng-src="profileImage" class="profileImage">');
                }
            }
        };
    })
;
```

now I wish to write a unit test for this (I know I should have done that first but I am just learning about tests). I have written the following:

```
it('should display a specific image', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        //$rootScope.profileImage = "srcOfImage";
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $scope.profileImage = "srcOfImage";

        var element = angular.element('<div profile-image="profileImage"></div>')
        element = $compile(element)($scope)
        console.log(element);

        var imgElem = element.find('img');
        expect(imgElem.length).toBe(1);
        expect(imgElem.eq(0).attr('src')).toBe('srcOfImage');


    }));
```

Now the test fails in this scenario (other tests where no $scope.profileImage is available has passed). When I out put the element I have created I get the following:

```
LOG: {0: <div profile-image="profileImage" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><img ng-src="profileImage" class="profileImage"></div>, length: 1}
```

So everything works but the `profile-image="profileImage"` in the `var element = angular.element('<div profile-image="profileImage"></div>')` is being taken as a literal string. It is not showing the value `'srcOfImage'`. What am I doing wrong?

The error looks like so:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Profile Image Directive should display a specific image FAILED
-src="prExpected undefined to be 'srcOfImage'.>, length: 1}
```

Big thanks for any advice / help / explanations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior because:

```
element.append('<img ng-src="profileImage" class="profileImage">');
```

appends a normal DOM image ***without compilation***, so the properties are added as they are.
Try:

```
element.append('<img ng-src="profileImage" class="profileImage">');
$compile(element.contents())(scope); //adding this line to compile the image.
```

Remember to declare the `$compile` service in your directive:

```
.directive('profileImage',function($compile) {
```

One more problem is you have to use `ng-src` with `{{}}` like this:

```
ng-src="{{profileImage}}"
```

Your final directive looks like this:

```
.directive('profileImage',function($compile) { //declare $compile service.
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                profileImage: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                if(!scope.profileImage) {
                    element.addClass('icon-default-profile-image defaultProfileImage');
                } else {
                    element.append('<img ng-src="{{profileImage}}" class="profileImage">');
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope); //adding this line to compile the image.
                }
            }
        };
    })
;
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice however I'm still not getting things right, I have changed the code to the following and I still get the same error?

 `var element = angular.element('<div profile-image="profileImage"></div>');
        element = $compile(element)($scope);
        //element.append('<img ng-src="profileImage" class="profileImage">');
        element = $compile(element.contents())($scope);`

Comment: Just to add to the above - the element still doesn't compile

Comment: @Mike Sav: did you add it inside the directive? Check my updated answer

Comment: @Mike Sav: also use `{{}}` with `ng-src`

Comment: Right, I got confused, I have now updated the directive with the compile and the {{}} however when I run my test again the output is like so: LOG: {0: <div profile-image="profileImage" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><img ng-src="{{profileImage}}" class="profileImage ng-scope"></div>, length: 1}

Comment: @Mike Sav: Actually, the img has been compiled. If you look at the src, you would see `"http://fiddle.jshell.net/RWmVW/1/show/srcOfImage"`. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RWmVW/1/ . Without `$compile(element.contents())(scope);`, you would see that src is an empty string.

Comment: @Mike Sav: also try taking a look at the `outerHTML` property in both cases. (with and without compile)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the directives works, the test in karma just doesn't? It still out puts "ng-src="{{profileImage}}", If you have any further help Khanh To let's move this to chat, stack says "Please avoid extended discussions in comments"

Comment: @Mike Sav: It seems like, $compile does not update ng-src in the current function, only when the browser picks up the next event in the events queue. I tried `console.log(element.find('img').attr('src'));`, it returns undefined. I also tried debugging, inside the function `console.log(element.find('img'));` logged an image without compilation (this element will be updated later when the browser picks up the next event, that's why without debugging we saw it logged correctly). I tried wrapping the function inside $timeout and it works http://jsfiddle.net/RWmVW/2/